# Applescript - Call an Error and continue

Tags: triggers, dialog, applescript, continue

I'm trying to trigger an error on purpose and then continue my script.

```
Error number -2700
```

triggers an "Unkown Error" error but it also ends the script with the returning value of -2700 instead of 0.

Also, I don't want the script to end after the error but to continue when you press the "OK" button.

The reason I want to do this is so that I won't have to make an Error dialog in every language myself.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
try
    1 / 0
on error errMsg number errNum
    tell me
        activate
        display alert errMsg & return & return & errNum buttons "OK"
    end tell
end try

beep 3
```

Comment: That would require me to make one for each language and inserting the Error number -2700 snippet just ends the script.

Comment: Will you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the effect of you getting an error (although there's nothing wrong) and then execute some code. This is for testing purposes only.

Comment: The code above does throw an error with 1/0. You would place any code you want to execute after an error occurs between the on error and end try.

Answer (score 0):

(The comments mess up my code, that's why I post a new answer)

"For each language" sounds strange. Normally, you programme in a particular language and you'd write an error handling routine. In AppleScript this would be

```
try
  -- your script here
on error errMsg number errNum
  errorHandler(errMsg,errNum)
end try

on errorHandler (errMsg,errNum)
  display dialog errMsg & " (" & errNum & ")."
end errorHandler
```

Comment: This would still require me to write the error message corresponding to the error number thou, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. I don't think it gets easier than this.